# Can an email address or its creation be traced back to me?

Tags: vpn

I created an email address from my laptop using a VPN. I then created a blog with this email address also using a VPN. However, someone is trying to track down this site to find out who the owner is (me). Assuming there was no malfunction with the VPN, how can this person find out I created this? I was thinking that if they tried to get a court ordered subpoena for the host blog site, who could then give information about the email used to create the site. The email address is a gmail address.

Can the gmail give me away? Obviously I didn't use any phone number or any real credentials.

Comment: So there is no email, but an email address ... and yes, of course.

Comment: Did you register a domain for you blog? If so the domain registration will have billing and technical contacts. You can use a privacy service to hide it but that wouldn't resist a court order.

Comment: Accorsing to your commets below Steffen Ullrichs answer you don't know much about online tracking. One can assume that you used your personal computer with your usual browser for this? For companys like Google tracking this back to you would be trivially easy. Why did I mention operating system and browser? Well, there's a lot of ways you can be tracked in the internet. From your browser to your fonts to your mouse cursor movement up to imperfections in the sillicon that affect javascript execution speeds. Use your favorite search engine to search for the TAILS operating system.

Comment: TAILS isn't a magic bullet but it might be very informative. Perfect anonymity is hard to archieve. Also, VPNs are a shady business. Never trust a VPN you don't host yourself

Answer (score 1):

Given that you use gmail Google has probably a lot of history from where this account was created and used and how it relates to other google services (search etc). If Google can be forced to provide this information then it will probably easy to narrow down or find out who you are based on all this collected information.

Comment: what if i only used the email to set up the blog? what other info could google have and what do you mean they have info from where this account was created? cause i used a vpn so doesn't that cover me in terms of where my account was created?

Comment: also, what is the liklihood of google handing over this information?

Comment: @user477465: This pretty much depends on what they are forced to by law. And depends depends on what you are charged with. For more questions in this legal area try law.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @user477465: Google knows what you search for when using their search engine. Google knows what sites you visit since they own tracking and ad delivery which is embedded in many sites etc. This can create a good profile of a person. And Google is probably able to associate these information with your GMail account.

Comment: thanks! when you say google knows what sites you visit, is that only when you're signed into the google account? for exmaple, if I signed out of my gmail, then are my google searches still associated with the account?

Comment: @user477465: Google (and others) track you too if you are not signed in. And it is possible to associate these information with the information gained when you are  signed in.

Answer (score 0):

You should also think about your browser fingerprint. Using VPN to create a anonymous gmail account, then using the same browser to connect to your main gmail account (with or without VPN) could be enough to link both accounts.
If Google watch, record, and can be forced to reveal it...